# How to identify a value inside of a tuple in a python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, indexing, tuples

I'm looking for some pythonic solution to check if there are True or False in a tuple inside of a list.

I did like this:

```
varList = [(True,)]
temp = varList.pop(0)
result = temp[temp.index(True,)]
print result

#############
# If there are more complex result 
varList = [(True, False, False), (True, False)]
```

How to do this in a better way?

Comment: Will `varList` always contain a single element? Do you want to treat `1` and `0` as `True` and `False` like Python does?

Comment: Give example for varlist . Does it contain only true or false ? if yes will it be always as first element ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands the problem is sometimes can be there more than one logical test result. 
I try to use some pythonic way to check presence of True (because it is the focus).

Comment: @IsaqueDaniel Can you show some more complex examples of `varList` and your desired output?

Comment: The new example input is better, but what's its desired output?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I need to verify if there is "True" result and in which position.

Comment: And you are unable to tell us what that is for that example? Why are you making this so hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want also want to return the index of the tuple as well as the index of the occurence within than tuple, you can try:

```
  def isValueInList(varList, value):
       return [(varList[lst][i],lst,i) for lst in range(len(varList)) for i in range(len(varList[lst])) if varList[lst][i] == value]

 print(isValueInList(varList, True))
```

The result will be:

```
[(True, 0, 0), (True, 1, 0)]
```

where:

First argument means that value was found.

Second argument specifies the index of the tuple within the list.

Third argument specifies the index of the value that was found within that tuple.

Here is the suggested edit using `enumerate`:

```
def isValueInList(varList, value):

   return [(val,innerInd, tupInd) for tupInd, tup in enumerate(varList) for innerInd, val in enumerate(tup) if val==value]

print(isValueInList(varList, True))
```

The result will be:

```
[(True, 0, 0), (True, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: I will try to edit it though, because as @StefanPochmann suggests, there is a more convenient way of doing it by using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3):

if your intention is to check if the value True exists in a tuple or tuples you could use [any](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) keyword like the following :

```
true_exists = [ any(subset) for subset in varList ]
```

you also check if all the elements are True using the [all](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all) keyword

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
result = True in varList[0]
```

Comment: A more pythonic way for boolean values is to use `any` and `all` functions. Note howerever, that they may yield different results compared to the `True in` and `False in` approach when the list is empty.